# We can only use RWMutex without volatile?

Tags: go

In https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_10, this program is not safe as below, there is no guarantee to print the newest msg

```
type T struct {
    msg string
}

var g *T

func setup() {
    t := new(T)
    t.msg = "hello, world"
    g = t
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    for g == nil {
    }
    print(g.msg)
}
```

In JAVA, its ok for volatile g, we have to use rwmutex to keep printing the newest msg in golang as below?

```
type T struct {
    msg    string
    rwlock sync.RWMutex
}

var g = &T{}

func setup() {
    g.rwlock.Lock()
    defer g.rwlock.Unlock()
    g.msg = "hello, world"
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    printMsg()
}

func printMsg() {
    g.rwlock.RLock()
    defer g.rwlock.RUnlock()
    print(g.msg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options.

Busy wait. This program completes in the current version of of Go, but the spec does not guarantee it.  [Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/S1AposnPNl0).

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

type T struct {
    msg string
}

var g unsafe.Pointer

func setup() {
    t := new(T)
    t.msg = "hello, world"
    atomic.StorePointer(&g, unsafe.Pointer(t))
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    var t *T
    for {
        runtime.Gosched()

        t = (*T)(atomic.LoadPointer(&g))
        if t != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    print(t.msg)
}
```

Channel. [Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v979GzIMryO).

```
func setup(ch chan struct{}) {
    t := new(T)
    t.msg = "hello, world"
    g = t
    close(ch) // signal that the value is set
}

func main() {
    var ch = make(chan struct{})
    go setup(ch)
    <-ch // wait for the value to be set.
    print(g.msg)
}
```

[WaitGroup](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup). [Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v979GzIMryO).

```
var g *T

func setup(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    t := new(T)
    t.msg = "hello, world"
    g = t
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go setup(&wg)
    wg.Wait()
    print(g.msg)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you use channel.

```
type T struct {
    msg string
    doneC chan struct{}
}

func NewT() *T {
    return &T{
        doneC: make(chan struct{}, 1),
    }
}

func (t *T) setup() {
    t.msg = "hello, world"
    t.doneC <- struct{}{}
}

func main() {
    t := NewT()
    go t.setup()
    <- t.doneC // or use select to set a timeout
    fmt.Println(t.msg)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try atomic.Value for your race field

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).